# Eclipse CDT - How to build googletest unit tests as a separate project?

Tags: c++, eclipse, unit-testing, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I have two projects. One called `projectA` and the other called `projectA-tests`.

The first project is my actual project, and the second project contains [GoogleTest](https://github.com/google/googletest) unit tests for classes in `projectA`.

I have coded one very simple unit test so far and everything builds OK. Note that this first simple test depends on a single .h file of `projectA` that has only a static class method defined in the same `.h` file (no `.cpp` file). It's actually a "StringUtils" class with methods like ::startsWith() and so on.

After adding a second test I'm having linking problems. This second test depends con a Class of `projectA` that is declared in a `.h` file and defined in a `.cpp` file. I'm getting an **undefined reference** regarding this Class, trying to build this second test.

`projectA-tests` compiler settings are configured to include  `projectA/src` in project -> properties -> C/C++ build -> settings -> C++ compiler -> includes. (I guess this is why the first compiles ok, because it only requires a .h file which is covered by this "includes" setting).

**What I don't know is how to configure the C++ linker in `projectA-test` to include all `.o` files of `projectA` in the linkage process.**

**I'm more experienced in Java, and the equivalent would be simply adding the other project source folder as dependency of the build path. Whay is Eclipse CDT's C++ equivalent?**

Thanks!

Comment: Create a library from the `.o` files of projectA and link that to projectA-test.

Comment: and then add it as a referenced library like I did with the gtest library itself? Any advice on how to do that in Eclipse CDT?